# string concatenation with "\x" hex character escape

Tags: c, string

How do I create a string that contain multiple `'\x41'` or with arbitrary `'\xnn'` by copy from some give string for example:

`char * string1 = "4141414141414141";`
or `char * string2 = "bde54d7ee10a2122";`

And I would like my `char * string3` become something like:
   `char * string3 = "\xbd\xe5\x4d\x7e\xe1\x0a\x21\x22";`
or `char * string3 = "\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41";`

Here is the code that I am trying to do, but it doesn't work.

```
char * string1 = "4141414141414141";
char c;
char * slash_x = "\\x";
int len = strlen(string1);
char * string3 = (char *) malloc(9);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (0 == i % 2) {
        printf("start\n");
        j = i;
        strcat(salt_empty, slash_x);
        c = string[j];
        printf("%c\n", c);
        strncat(salt_empty, &c, 1);
        j++;
        c = string[j];
        printf("%c\n", c);
        strncat(salt_empty, &c, 1);
    }
}
printf("%s\n", string3);
```

So the output with `string3` will be `"\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41"` instead of `"AAAAAAAA"` at console.

How could I fix the code in order to get `"AAAAAAAA"`

If the string1 is `"bde54d7ee10a2122"`, then the `string3` output at console would be `��M~
!"`

Comment: I believe I need to fix the slash_x to something like "\x", but if I use"\x", then will have compiler error.

Comment: No, you cannot fix your code this way.  See my answer below.

Comment: You should change to misleading title to *Converting hex string to actual characters*

Comment: There is no such thing as "*`“\x”` hex character escape*".

Comment: @alk: what version of the C standard are you referring to?  hex character escape sequences have been standardized for eons.

Comment: Hu, you are correct @chqrlie! To early, hadn't had any coffee when posting this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert the string by re-interpreting it from its source form.  Use this instead (inefficient, but simple):

```
char *string1 = "4141414141414141";
int i, j, len = strlen(string1) & ~1;
char string3[len / 2 + 1];
for (i = j = 0; i < len; i += 2, j++) {
    char buf[3];
    memcpy(buf, string1 + i, 2);
    buf[2] = '\0';
    string3[j] = strtol(buf, NULL, 16);
}
string3[j] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", string3);
```

Comment: The allocated string is long enough for what OP is _trying_ to do, but not long enough for what is actually being done.

Comment: Right, because the "\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41" it only takes 8 bytes, and 1 bytes for '\0' I guess.

Comment: Indeed the OP is confused.  The question uses contradictory terms.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
char string1[] = {0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0};
```

Answer (score 0):

For each pair of characters in the source string, determine the hex value of each character in the pair, combine them to come up with the encoded character, then store the result in your destination string.

Comment: How do I combine them to come up with the encoded character for each pair of substring??